# Powershell report from Exchange and AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I've got this script that gives me report about AD users that are OWA enabled.

I need to add to this users who have owe disabled.

Anyone out there who knows how I change this script to get that result to?

```
Import-Module "ActiveDirectory"

$mailboxes = Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize 10000

"DisplayName;ActiveSync;Owa;SamAccountName;ExpiriationDate;AccountStatus;Department;Title;Description;Company;Office;LastLogonTime;"

foreach ($m in $mailboxes) {
  $Display=$false
  if ($m.OWAEnabled        -eq $true) { $Display=$true }
  if ($Display -eq $true) {
    $a = Get-ADUser $m.DistinguishedName -properties *
    $s = Get-MailboxStatistics $m.DistinguishedName
    "{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9};{10};{11};" -f $m.DisplayName,$m.ActiveSyncEnabled,$m.OWAEnabled,$m.samAccountName,$a.AccountExpirationDate,[string]$a.Enabled,$a.Department,$a.title,$a.description,$a.company,$a.office,$s.LastLogonTime
  }

}
```

Comment: change the `$m.OWAEnabled` condition to `$false`?

Comment: remove  the two `if` conditions and remove `$Display=$false` .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line

```
if ($m.OWAEnabled        -eq $true) { $Display=$true }
```

means : if the `OWAEnabled` property is set to `$true`, then display the user

You could simply change it to

```
$Display=$true
```

meaning : user will be displayed in any case

To simplify further, you can even remove everything related to `$Display` which was only used to filter :

```
Import-Module "ActiveDirectory"

$mailboxes = Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize 10000

"DisplayName;ActiveSync;Owa;SamAccountName;ExpiriationDate;AccountStatus;Department;Title;Description;Company;Office;LastLogonTime;"

foreach ($m in $mailboxes) {
    $a = Get-ADUser $m.DistinguishedName -properties *
    $s = Get-MailboxStatistics $m.DistinguishedName
    "{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9};{10};{11};" -f $m.DisplayName,$m.ActiveSyncEnabled,$m.OWAEnabled,$m.samAccountName,$a.AccountExpirationDate,[string]$a.Enabled,$a.Department,$a.title,$a.description,$a.company,$a.office,$s.LastLogonTime    
}
```

If you start to play with AD PowerShell cmdlets, you should learn the basics to understand what the scripts you use really do, or you may end up ruining your AD :).